# FirebaseMessagingService push notification creation - how to set icon?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service, android-notifications

I want to set icon for my push notification which is created by `FirebaseMessagingService`. Problem is that these notifications are created by system internally (probably in function `onStartCommand()` which is final and I don't have access to it. I don't know from which source is icon for this notification set. Normally if you create notification you can set icon by `NotificationManager`, but this process is done internally by Firebase. Reason why I want to change icon is because my icon for app has transparent background (its vector drawable (.svg). But for some reason it is shown as square.

Is there any way how to modify notification icon inside `FirebaseMessagingService`?

Answer (score -1):

**Use this Function for display notification**

```
  public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message,Intent intent) {
    Random random = new Random();
    NotificationManager notifManager = null;
    if (notifManager == null) {
        notifManager = (NotificationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=null;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;

    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    String notificationId = String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(10000));

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    Integer.parseInt(notificationId),
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel("Test");
        if (mChannel == null) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel("Test", title, importance);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, "Test");

    }else{
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, "Test");
    }

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setTicker(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            //.setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(notificationId), notification);


}
```

Comment: My problem is not about showing notification. Your code is about creating notification in code. FirebaseMessagingService is showing and firing notification in a background without any tracking about it. You also cant check notificationId to get that notification also (you dont know id). Payload from notification is thrown to activity bundle for example. My question was if there is some method to set notification icon as default icon for this Service. Probably similar process as your function is happening inside `onStartCommand()` - function is final so you cant use it or access its parameters